# Classic ASP 'Requests Executing' never greater than 1

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, asp-classic, perfmon

We have a complex app that serves AJAX JSON streams (using ADO to grab the data) using brief ASP servlets. Any given session can fire up from 10-20 of these requests simultaneously. We encountered a significant performance problem way earlier than we expected as load built. (Server is a dual-XEON, RAID 5, 4gb, etc). Sleuthing around in perfmon we noticed that the 'Requests Executing' figure is perpetually stuck at 1. Never gets any higher. Research indicates that numbers of 20-50 are not uncommon. Requests Queued will hover around 10-20 and Wait Time climbs as well.

We have fiddled with ASPProcessorThreadMax set to 40 from default of 25 with no effect. It seems to be only able to work a single request at a time, which, needless to say, won't work. I can't find anything that describes this particular problem. Anny help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123453/problem-with-ihttpasynchandler-and-asp-net-requests-executing-counter does it make a difference if your requests are sync or async ? also if you replace the ADO with some fixed data, does the problem still exist ?

Comment: Are you dealing with session variables ? see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326817/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-concurrent-requests

Comment: Why have you included the asp.net tag for an asp-classic problem?  The two comments so far point to ASP.NET answers which probably are clues but are not definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP Session object is constrained to a Single Threaded Apartment (STA).  As a result requests to ASP scripts for the same session can only be processed sequentially.

An additional reason why you might only ever see 1 executing ASP script even across multiple sessions is where debugging has be enabled for ASP.  This causes the ASP processing to ignore ASPProcessorThreadMax and pretend it were set to 1.

To eliminate the problem [ensure debugging is not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1138210/185123) and turn off "Enable Session State".  If you are using the Session object in your code you will need to find an alternative, like DB backed state.

However, how many active concurrent sessions are you expecting in the live production?  Perhaps the overall user experience will not truely be impacted by the serialisation of requests per session.