# IIS does not scale, but cpu does not max out either, why is it slowing down

Tags: c#, iis, scalability, cpu, application-pool

I have an application where clients connect to IIS with websockets.
IIS then create a local proxy for IPC to connect to executable.

So IIS is sort of a middle man.

As more connection come in the slower the whole architecture gets.

So there is a bottleneck somewhere.

Interesting thing is that CPU does not pass 25% usage. I have not put any limit on the CPU utils.

the issue is not the code as a function that was taking say 100 milliseconds now taking 1000 milliseconds. And These functions are not network bound. 
Simple image conversions. 
I also check to see if I am blocking on locks or anything.

One would thing the more users joins the system more of these image conversions occur and more cpu is used.
But again the cpu utilization is not changing and it is stuck around 25%

Since execution of even the simplest function is slowing down, I am guessing there is a limit on the application pool of how much CPU it can use. Again I checked the AppPool settings and there is no limit.

any suggestions on how to go about this ?

Comment: let me think, quad core cpu so 25% is 100% of one core

Comment: @Fredou, could be, but it would be strange if the worker threads weren't distributed across cores.

Comment: Have you thrown perf mon on the nic, disk, and memory yet?  These are other key components to check on when running into IIS performance issues such as this.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a CPU affinity setting either through the code or system settings.

You can set processor affinity (and thus limit to 1 processor) per application pool, which would effectively limit the app that runs in that pool to use one processor. This will limit the w3wp process to only use one processor, and thus if you have a quad core CPU it would run at 25%. Here you can find the details on changing this here through your IIS settings: [this:http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu)

You may also check Task Manager and right click the process and click "Set Afinity.." and see if your limiting IIS to one core.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: On Task manager when right click on w3wp.exe and look at affinity, I see all 11 CPUs are selected. 
So 11 cpu  is 2047 in dec and 0X7FF hex. So I set the AppPool affinity Enabled to true and Affinity mask to 2047. Which means use all CPUs. Still I dont get passed the 20% to 30% but the app just slows down more and more. I have also removed all the other app pools to make sure. I am running it on default app pool.

Answer (score 2):

You can check process affinity for the Application Pool Process.  That may be the reason you are stuck on 25%.

Beyond processor affinity, if your requests are long running, you maybe running up against default limits to the number of concurrent requests per CPU that IIS allows (especially in integrated mode....12).  The 25% on a quad core CPU hints that affinity is your problem, but if it isn't, you can check this as well.  Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123453/problem-with-ihttpasynchandler-and-asp-net-requests-executing-counter/6128861#6128861)